# flask - python How to read a file and output to browser line by line and formats

Tags: python, io, flask, readfile

I am developing a flask-python application. I want to read a file and out put the content with line-breaks and white spaces intact. Below is the code I have now. But it outputs all the lines as a single stream without any line break. What is the correct way to do it?

```
with open(anupath, 'r')as f:
    content=""
    for line in f:
        content += line + '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your response is likely being treated as HTML by the browser, which collapses line breaks (among plenty of other things). If you want your file to be displayed as-is, set the parameter `mimetype='text/plain'` on your flask `Response` object before returning it:

```
return Response(content, mimetype='text/plain')
```